# Ask users for input data and run after they input "done"

Tags: python, input

I would like to write a code/program for asking user for their input filenames(Some users have more than 10 input files) and then once they press "done" then the program will executed all the files.

For example, user have 3 files.

1) They entered the 3 file names
2) They press "done"
3) Program runs the 3 files (I already wrote my program so I dont need this but it should be something like saving the 3 files in a list [file1, file2, file] since my program can use for x in list, then perform loading each file)

If possible, it will be good to be able to count how many files they entered.

My code is as below:

```
a = 0 
a = input("Please enter your filenames without the '.txt' and press 'Done' to run " )
a += 1
print("---------- File {} ----------".format(a))
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I try to use for loop but it will be very long codes for just asking user inputs. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your attempt at a loop? It would be shorter than copying this 10 times

Answer (score 2):

Accumulate a list of inputs, then break the loop when done.

```
names = []
while True:
    a = input("file name or 'Done'")
    if a == "Done":
        break
    else:
        names.append(a)
# user typed done
print("entered {} names".format(len(names)))
for n in names:
   print('{}.txt'.format(n))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. I will refer to this.